# Can't emit from method defined outside of socket connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to use a custom object's method to emit to a socket connection. The object is defined outside of the socket connection, but then instantiated inside of it. Code and error follows.

## app.js

```
...
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  report = new Report();

  socket.on('dataChange', function(newData) {
    report.update(newData);
  });
});

function Report () {
  this.update = function (data) {
    socket.emit('updateReport', { data: data });
  }
}
```

## Error

Node gives me the following error.

> socket.emit('updateReport', { data: data });
>   ^
>
> ReferenceError: socket is not defined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could pass `socket` to `Report` like this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  report = new Report(socket);

  socket.on('dataChange', function(newData) {
    report.update(newData);
  });
});

function Report (socket) {
  this.update = function (data) {
    socket.emit('updateReport', { data: data });
  }
}
```

That way, `socket` is accessible in `Report`.

However, you used `report` as a variable that's *not* local to the connection handler. Are you sure you're not overwriting `report` across connections? It seems you rather want a report per connection. In that case, prepend `var` to the `report` assignment.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and now I understand how this pattern is supposed to work. Also, the second part of your question definitely saved some headache in the future.

Comment: can you put a 'socket.on' within the Report function? Will it perform the callback when the event is fired?

Comment: @The Hawk: Yes, you can. But instead of `report`, you'd have to define `var instance = this;` in `Report`, and then access `instance` the `dataChange` handler instead.