# accessing socket outside the socket.on('connection') closure

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Below is part of app.js, it has socket connection with client

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (soc) {
    soc.emit('news', { status: 'connected' });
});
```

What I want to do is access the soc var outside the connection closure, like this

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (soc) {
        do something magical here so I can access soc from outside
});
soc.emit('news', { status: 'connected' });
```

What additional technique need to add in to archive this structure?

Answer (score 6):

you need to reference your socket io variable in your server code:

`io.sockets.emit('news', { status: 'connected' });`

so in your sample code, it could look something like this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (soc) {
    emit();
});

function emit(){
    io.sockets.emit('news', { status: 'connected' });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
var foo;

io.on('connection', function(soc){
    foo = new Foo(soc);
});

function Foo (socket){
    this.emit = function () {
        if(socket)
        {
            socket.emit('msg');
        }
    }
}
```

After somebody is connected you can call `foo.emit();`

This answer might help you:
[Can't emit from method defined outside of socket connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795069/cant-emit-from-method-defined-outside-of-socket-connection)

Comment: That would only allow one `socket.io` connection to be used like that (since the `connection` event is called for every connection, the global `foo` will be overwritten each time). Might be the use case here, I don't know.

Comment: For multiple connections you can use `foo` as an array and push the socket in it at each connection

Comment: And remove it once the connection is gone :)